# Can it be decidable for any polynomials to have the intersecting point?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, systems-of-equations, model-theory, computability

Give system of polynomials$$P_1(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)=0,$$$$\vdots,$$$$P_k(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)=0$$
Can it be decidable for thoses polynomials to have the intersecting point ?

Comment: What is **the** intersecting point? And dicidable (decidable?) in which sense?

Comment: I interpret his question as asking if there is a deterministic method to determine whether the intersection of the root sets of several multivariate polynomials is the empty set.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, thank you for you comments, the intersecting point is the set of zeros of the system of polynomials $P_1(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)=0$. Decidable means there is an algorithm that decide whether they have intersecting points or not. I vaguely recall that the question is decidable.

Comment: @NovaDenizen, yes, you are right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We answer the question for polynomials with rational coefficients.

If we are interested in whether there is a solution over the reals, or over the complex numbers, the answer is yes.

More strongly, the first-order theory of each is decidable. The decidability of the first-order theories was first proved by Tarski.

If we are interested in integer solutions, the answer is no, by the negative solution to Hilbert's Tenth Problem. The final piece in the proof was provided by Matiyasevich.

If we are interested in rational solutions, whether or not there exists a decision procedure is an open problem.

Comment: It's an interesting curiosity that the problem is decidable but not tractable: it's NP-complete for complex-valued machines a la Smale-Blum-Shub.

Comment: Thank you, yes, by Tarski theorem ,both $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are decidable. And the third case is about the integral solution to the Diophantine equations. The fourth case is what is new to me, I know it is still open now.

Comment: There is a fairly big literature for other rings. A good summary was made a few years ago by Bjorn Poonen, who has contributed many results.

Comment: @KevinCarlson,BCSS model is not equivalent to standard one, even some computable function by standard model is non-computable in BCSS model. So, what is the meaning of NP-complete for complex-valued machines a la Smale-Blum-Shub? see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/186226/the-link-and-equivalence-between-variant-definition-of-computation-model-and-com  for reference.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, could you give  reference for  summary  made a few years ago by Bjorn Poonen,  thank you.

Comment: Has this anything to do with [Geometric Complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_complexity_theory)? I think they ask if a polytope has an integral point as I read in a survey of Fortnow.

Comment: @XL_at_China: I was referring to [this article.](http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/aws2003.pdf)

Comment: @AndréNicolas, thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome. Over the integers, we already get undecidability for quartics in many variables. Quadratics are decidable, cubics are open.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, thank you for the detailed comment. And Sun Zhi-Wei has some result about the number of variables,powers and  undecidability.

Comment: @XL_at_China it's just the same definition as in the classical case: the length of an input is measured in complex numbers, for instance, the length of the vector of coefficients of polynomials, rather than in bits.

Answer (score 3):

Given an ideal $I$ of $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ with $k$ an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, you can effectively compute a $Gr\ddot{o}bner$ basis for it. Checking whether $Z(I)$ is empty is equivalent to checking whether $1$ is in the  $Gr\ddot{o}bner$ basis (by Hilbert's Nullstellensatz). Checking whether $1$ is in the  $Gr\ddot{o}bner$ basis is a trivial check.

Maybe the same works in characteristic $>0$ as well.

As André Nicolas says the problem is much more difficult over non-algebraically closed fields, even if you restrict to just smooth projective curves.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: So ugly is my editing. But .....